# Firebase admin SDK in ionic2: Cannot find module "dns"

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, ionic2, firebase-admin

I'm trying to use Firebase admin SDK as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) in ionic2. but when I call `admin.initializeApp`, I get this error:

```
  import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
  ....
  admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
    clientEmail: "foo@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n<KEY>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
  }),
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
});


Error: Cannot find module "dns"
at webpackMissingModule (http://localhost:8101/build/main.js:178777:75)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8101/build/main.js:178777:156)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8101/build/main.js:180128:30)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8101/build/main.js:20:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8101/build/main.js:178726:18)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8101/build/main.js:20:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8101/build/main.js:132218:15)
at Object.internals.rfc3986 (http://localhost:8101/build/main.js:132683:30)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8101/build/main.js:20:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8101/build/main.js:42488:13)
```

I have installed dns module by `npm install dns`, but still get this error. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using the Admin SDK (`firebase-admin`) instead of the regular client SDK (`firebase`) in your Ionic app? The Admin SDK is for server-side development, not app development.

Comment: Yes, I'm building an admin dashboard app to be used by admins only

Comment: @jacobawenger I occasionally need to sign in as another user and fix an issue for them on the app. What is the best practice for doing so if not having an admin app?

Comment: Sorry, the Firebase Admin SDK is meant for development on servers, not in browsers (or mobile web environments like Ionic). So, this is probably just one of many issues you will run into while trying to use it like that. The best practice is to edit a user's information in some admin dashboard, either the Firebase Console itself or some app which proxies request to a server running the Admin SDKs.

Comment: Proxy request works!